# How do I move views with RecyclerView.OnScrollListener, while keeping rotation sanity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener

I have a layout with a RecyclerView (simple vertical list). When the list is scrolled up, some views (including the recyclerview) move with it and stick to the top of the screen. Scrolling down, they move down until they return to their initial position. Their translationY are tied to how much the list has been scrolled up or down.

Problem is, I have a static layout for landscape, so rotation does all sorts of weird things to the layout. How do I prevent this? In other words, how do I keep the views within setTranslationY bounds?

The layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    ...
    >
    <Some other stuff/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerLayout"
        >
        ...  contains things ... 
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the code:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        scrollY = scrollY - dy  //  float, to keep the total vertical scroll amount 
        final int maxTop = rootLayout.getTop()  //  Maximum translationY allowed, sticky to top
        containerLayout.setTranslationY(maxTop > scrollY ? maxTop : scrollY)  //  if it reached the top, stay there
        recyclerView.setTranslationY(maxTop > scrollY ? maxTop : scrollY)  //  the same
    }
```

This works well enough. The problem is when I rotate the device, the layouts move into wacky positions or entirely off-screen because of the recycler view behaviour.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm losing my sanity here.